# Querying json key name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json

Given json like this...

```
{"setting1":"A","setting2":"B","setting3":"C"}
```

I would like to see results like...

```
+----------+-------+
|   name   | value |
+----------+-------+
| setting1 | A     |
| setting2 | B     |
| setting3 | C     |
+----------+-------+
```

My struggle is I'm trying to find out how to extract the key's name (i.e., "setting1", "setting2", "setting3", etc.)

I could do something like the following query, but I don't know how many settings there will be and what their names will be, so I'd like something more dynamic.

```
SELECT
    B.name,
    B.value
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH
    (
        setting1 varchar(50) '$.setting1',
        setting2 varchar(50) '$.setting2',
        setting3 varchar(50) '$.setting3'
    ) A
CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
            ('setting1', A.setting1),
            ('setting2', A.setting2),
            ('setting3', A.setting3)
    ) B (name, value)
```

With XML, I could do something simple like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<settings><setting1>A</setting1><setting2>B</setting2><setting3>C</setting3></settings>'
SELECT
    A.setting.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(50)') name,
    A.setting.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') value
FROM @xml.nodes('settings/*') A (setting)
```

Any way to do something similar with SQL Server's json functionality?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand has written about json key value in [Advanced JSON Techniques](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4138/advanced-json-techniques-in-sql-server-2016--part-3/)

```
SELECT x.[Key], x.[Value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@Json, '$') AS x;
```

Return

```
Key         Value
------------------
setting1    A
setting2    B
setting3    C
```

Comment: I like how this guy comes out of nowhere and smashes this answer out!

Answer (score 0):

**Option Using a Table**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,JSON_String varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'{"setting1":"A","setting2":"B","setting3":"C"}')

Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable  A
 Cross Apply (values (try_convert(xml,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(JSON_String,'"',''),'{','<row '),'}','"/>'),':','="'),',','" '))) ) B (XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Name   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as C1(r)
                 Cross Apply C1.r.nodes('./@*') as C2(attr)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name        Value
1   setting1    A
1   setting2    B
1   setting3    C
```

**Option Using a String Variable**

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '{"setting1":"A","setting2":"B","setting3":"C"}'

Select C.* 
 From  (values (try_convert(xml,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@String,'"',''),'{','<row '),'}','"/>'),':','="'),',','" '))) ) A (XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Name   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  A.XMLData.nodes('/row') as C1(r)
                 Cross Apply C1.r.nodes('./@*') as C2(attr)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Name       Value
setting1    A
setting2    B
setting3    C
```

Comment: Very clever workaround! Unfortunately, the json I'm working with is slightly more complicated than my example I gave, but the root of my question is looking to see if there is a way to get the key name from the json similarly to how you can get it with xml. Sadly it sounds like that's not possible? Here is some json closer to what I'm working with :{"setting1":{"global":"A","type":"1"},"setting2":{"global":"B","type":"1"},"setting3":{"global":"C","type":"1"}}

Comment: I was able to adapt your approach to my needs, however my real question was if you're able to use something like local-name() to get the key name in JSON. If you're able to definitively state that there is no way to do that and update your answer to say such then I'll accept this as an answer as it provides a pretty good workaround.

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth Actually, I spent a fair amount of time experimenting with 2016's JSON functionality (mostly because this was an intesting question), but I've yet to find/create a concise solution.  I may have another solution, but it requires my EXTRACT UDF.  It is modification to a parse udf which accept two non-like delimiters.

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth I added a second answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a TVF.

The following requires my Extract UDF.  This function was created because I was tired of extracting string (patindex,charindex,left,right, etc).  It is a modified tally parse which accepts two non-like delimiters.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,JSON_String varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'{"setting1":{"global":"A","type":"1"},"setting2":{"global":"B","type":"1"},"setting3":{"global":"C","type":"1"}} ')


Select A.ID
      ,B.Setting
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable  A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Setting = replace(replace(B1.RetVal,'"',''),'{','')
                      ,B2.RetVal
                 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.JSON_String,',',':{') B1
                 Join  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.JSON_String,':{','}') B2
                   on  B1.RetSeq=B2.RetSeq
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Name  = C1.RetVal
                      ,Value = C2.RetVal
                 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](','+B.RetVal,',"','":') C1
                 Join  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](B.RetVal+',',':"','",') C2
                   on  C1.RetSeq=C2.RetSeq
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Setting     Name    Value
1   setting1    global  A
1   setting1    type    1
1   setting2    global  B
1   setting2    type    1
1   setting3    global  C
1   setting3    type    1
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```