# Query of JSON Entry in SQL Table not working as expected

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I have been populating a SQL Server with JSON data and querying out the specific data needed.

I have what appeared to be a slightly different format presented to me from an API and I can't seem to see the pattern to get what i need.

The data returned from the API looks like this and is stored in a single line in a SQL Server

```
{"extrapolationLevel":1,"branchNames":["name"],"leafNames":["count(*)"],"values":{"Loading of page /webpage/page/Page1.asp":[4],"Loading of page /webpage/page/Page3.asp":[4],"Loading of page /webpage/page/Page2.asp":[3],"Loading of page /webpage/page/Page4.asp":[2],"Loading of page /webpage/page/Page5.asp":[7],"Loading of page /webpage/page/Page6.asp":[3]}}
```

[image: SQL Table Entry]

When I look at the data in a JSON Format this is what I see:

[image: JSON FORMAT]

I am trying to modify a previous query to extract both the name and the count:
So for instance.. I want results that show the data from the JSON, as well as 
both values.

Example

```
Date                        Page Name                                 Value 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-11-18 09:22:14.657     Loading of page /webpage/page/Page3.asp     4
```

I am uncertain how to include this as well---the name of the page ("Loading of page /webpage/page/PageX.asp") returned.

What is different this time is that I'm not getting the page values or the counts?

What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the image of output - I am not able to get the page name

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT d.[DATE], j.* 
FROM JSON_TABLE d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.log, '$.values') 
               WITH ([PageCount] int '$."Loading of page /webpage/page/Page1.asp"[0]') j
```

**UPDATE**:

I now have this query "almost there" How do I get rid of the JSON scaffolding around the value returned -the brackets

```
SELECT d.[DATE], x.[key], x.[value]
FROM JSON_Table as d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(d.log, '$.values')) AS X;
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what your query is currently outputting so we can see what behavior is wrong.

Comment: Added. Thank you . I appear to no tbe getting the page name :)

Comment: I may be wrong but you don't seem to be declaring the field whose value should be `'$."Loading of page /webpage/page/Page1.asp"[0]'`

Comment: I'm unclear how I would add that. Is that with another cross apply? What format would it take?

Comment: Just get the `[Key]` for the entries at that path?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233644/querying-json-key-name-in-sql-server

Comment: Looking at that now

Comment: @Jeff Mercado S0 I tried this way and i am not getting a syntax error --> SELECT d.[DATE], y.[Key], y.[Value] 
FROM JSON_TABLE as d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(d.log, '$.values')) AS X
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(X.[value], '$') as y;

Comment: Almost there.. Updated the question. I just need to purge the brackets and have the value as an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the key and value of the current property, use the `[key]` and `[value]` respectively. To extract values from these objects, you need to use `json_value`.

```
select d.[date], x.[key], json_value(x.[value], '$[0]')
from json_table d
cross apply openjson(d.[log], '$.values') x
```

Comment: That did it.. BTW... if I go to use an insert into will this  store the value as an int?

Comment: It should, the value in the json is a number so it should maintain its type. If it's not a number, you'll have to do the appropriate conversion.

Comment: Thank yo to this community for helping me learn to ask better questions and build off of what i have tried in the past. It's a loooonnnnggg road.. but at least there are friendly guides along the way !

Comment: It looks like I'm mistaken about the return value type for `json_value`. The type is actually `nvarchar(4000)` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value)). But for the purposes of inserting into other tables, it should still be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach here is to use `OPENJSON()` twice - with default schema and with explicit schema (using the [WITH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value) clause), because you have nested `JSON` objects in the `Log` column. When you use the default schema, the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`. When you use the explicit schema, you define the columns and type of the columns in the result table.

Note, that `JSON_VALUE()` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value) single text value of type `nvarchar(4000)`.

JSON and table:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "extrapolationLevel":1,
   "branchNames":[
      "name"
   ],
   "leafNames":[
      "count(*)"
   ],
   "values":{
      "Loading of page /webpage/page/Page1.asp":[
         4
      ],
      "Loading of page /webpage/page/Page3.asp":[
         4
      ],
      "Loading of page /webpage/page/Page2.asp":[
         3
      ],
      "Loading of page /webpage/page/Page4.asp":[
         2
      ],
      "Loading of page /webpage/page/Page5.asp":[
         7
      ],
      "Loading of page /webpage/page/Page6.asp":[
         3
      ]
   }
}'
CREATE TABLE Data (
   [Date] datetime,
   [Log] nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   ([Date], [Log])
VALUES
   (GETDATE(), @json)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   d.[Date],
   j1.[key] AS [Page],
   j2.[Count]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.[Log], '$.values') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
   [Count] int '$'
) j2
```

Result:

```
Date                Page                                    Count
18/11/2019 17:48:02 Loading of page /webpage/page/Page1.asp 4
18/11/2019 17:48:02 Loading of page /webpage/page/Page3.asp 4
18/11/2019 17:48:02 Loading of page /webpage/page/Page2.asp 3
18/11/2019 17:48:02 Loading of page /webpage/page/Page4.asp 2
18/11/2019 17:48:02 Loading of page /webpage/page/Page5.asp 7
18/11/2019 17:48:02 Loading of page /webpage/page/Page6.asp 3
```

Comment: Ah This is a method I was more familiar with but did not know how to format   I may end up leveraging both. Knowledge helps! Thank you also Zhorov!!! :)